# How to use the uArm Pro Python library

Tags: python-2.7, robotics

I am just getting started with uArm Pro and need to write a test controller in Python. I came across the python library for uArm on Github. How can I use it to my advantage?

Answer (score 1):

uArm provides baisc Movement on Python. The library only supports uArm Swift/SwiftPro. For Metal, please use pyuarm or pyuf instead.

pyuarm can be installed from PyPI, either manually downloading the files and installing as described below or using:

```
pip install pyuarm
```

Download the archive from https://github.com/uArm-Developer/uArm-Python-SDK . Unpack the archive, enter the uArm-Python-SDK directory and run:

```
python setup.py install
```

Try examples using this link https://github.com/uArm-Developer/uArm-Python-SDK/tree/2.0/examples/api